# Calculating frequency response of a RF tuned collector amplifier

Tags: rf, frequency-response, small-signal

I am doing a frequency response analysis for the following RF tuned circuit. I am not sure if I have done the right calculations so please correct me if there is any mistake.

[image]

The DC equivalent circuit can be easily made by replacing capacitors with open circuits and inductors as short circuit. The circuit has voltage divider biasing, so Thevenin equivalent voltage and resistance can be found. [image]

This gives $$ I_{CQ} = \beta (V_{TH} - V_{BE}(on) )/ (R_{TH} + (1+\beta) R_E) = 11mA$$

The AC source is a square wave generator with frequency 5 MHz and duty cycle 36%. Then following is the hybrid - π small signal equivalent circuit which I'm not sure is correct.

[image]

The following is the corresponding calculation:

$$ R_{ib}=\ r_\pi+(1+\ \beta)\ R_E=30.24\ k\Omega\ ;(\ \beta=135)$$
$$ R_i=\ R_{1\ }\left|\ \right|\ R_2\ \left|\ \right|\ R_{ib}\ =3.569\ k\Omega$$
$$ r_\pi=\ \frac{\beta V_T}{I_{CQ}}=319\ \Omega\ ;\ (V_T=0.026V)$$
$$ g_m=\frac{I_{CQ}}{V_T}\ =0.42\ A/V$$
$$ I_i=\frac{V_s}{\frac{1}{sC_c}+R_i}$$
$$ I_b=\left(\frac{R_B}{R_B+R_{ib}}\right)I_i$$
$$ R_B=R_{TH}=4047\ \Omega $$
$$ Z_L=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{sL}+sC_L}$$
$$ V_o=\ -g_mV_\pi Z_L $$
$$ V_\pi=I_br_\pi$$
$$ A_v(s)\ =-g_mr_\pi\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{sL}+sC_L}\right)\left(\frac{R_B}{R_B+R_{ib}}\right)\left(\frac{sC_c}{1+sR_iC_c}\right) $$

In the next step I replace s by jω and ω by 2πf after taking modulus, using frequency of square wave but again, I'm not sure if it is correct since there is no taking into account the duty cycle into calculation.

Lastly, I'm not sure if the small signal analysis is valid as square wave generator is a NE555 timer IC which is powered from 9 V DC source, whether the signal can be considered as small enough?

Comment: Why not use a simulator (free of course) for double checking theory and reality.

Comment: I'm actually open to using a simulator, I tried QucsStudio but it didn't have BFU690F transistor or any transistor >500MHz. Which simulator do you suggest that can serve the purpose??

Comment: I use microcap but many use LTspice. Microcap is still available to download from wiki archives: https://web.archive.org/web/20230214034946/http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip and the BFU690F is in its in-built library of parts (just checked).

Answer (score 1):

\$ Hybrid- \pi \$ is a strictly linear model, and the question, "At what AC amplitude does its linearity end?" is a good one.

A load resistor is missing. A load affects voltage gain, and it affects the point where the amplifier becomes non-linear. In OP's schematic, an antenna seems attached to transistor collector.
This antenna serves as a load impedance. For simplicity, assume the antenna is resonant, and assume it is matched to its feed impedance. For an example, a folded-dipole antenna might be 300 ohms, and might be fed with 300-ohm transmission line. So let's add a 300 ohm resistance from collector to +9V Vcc, and work out where the amplifier goes non-linear (crudely)...

This amplifier exits linear operation from one of two conditions:

- collector voltage falls below base voltage on its negative swing
- collector current bottoms out at 0mA when input swings to its negative peak.

Transistor base voltage rests near +3.4V, allowing collector to swing down from +9V by as much as 5.6V. Not quite as much, because a +ve-going input voltage reduces this headroom. But we'll use the 5.6V peak collector voltage as a crude estimate...
Peak collector current can be 11mA according to OP's calculation...

- 5.6/.011= 509 ohms

Since 509 ohms is greater than collector load of 300 ohms, collector voltage will go non-linear before collector current bottoms out. For an efficient Class-A amplifier, one might bias the transistor so that both current and voltage reach their respective non-linear points simultaneously.

For a 300-ohm collector load, bias current would increase to 19mA. To keep base voltage at +3.4V, emitter resistor would decrease from 200 ohms to about 140 ohms.
[image]

In this example, an AC peak amplitude of about 2.1V (pk) drives the transistor to the point of non-linear operation.
With an AC source *less than 2.1v (pk)*, a hybrid-PI transistor model is valid. Above this voltage, the transistor becomes non-linear (either due to current clipping or due to voltage clipping) making hybrid-PI invalid. LTspice's **AC analysis** can't be trusted for input signals larger than 2.1v (pk), *for this example*...below 2.1v (pk) you can compare **AC analysis** with hybrid-PI.
Above 2.1v (pk) at input, only LTspice **Transient analysis** is valid - it accounts for transistor non-linear operation. It will be valid even if Rantenna is removed. The downside to Transient analysis is extra computer time.
Even LTspice **Transient analysis** misses some transistor non-linearities - like transistor junction avalanche breakdown. For larger input signals, these can make LTspice results faulty.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. I have few questions. 1. Did you omit the coupling capacitor at collector before antenna on purpose? If so, why? 2. Why did you attach the other end of the load impedance/antenna to 9V source? 3. I don't completely understand your analysis, are you saying Hybrid - pi is invalid for this analysis and I should only rely on software?

Comment: \$R_{antenna}\$ sits 9V above GND. If the 9V DC supply has its GND connected to earth, then a tree falling on the antenna could short out the DC supply. In this case, a coupling capacitor would help. The antenna only radiates 5MHz signals - inductor L1 is a short-circuit for DC, so Rantenna sees no DC current. So a large-value coupling capacitor **or** a direct-coupled antenna both deliver the same RF power from transistor to Rantenna. A coupling capacitor might be safer as far as the DC supply is concerned.

Comment: Have added an edit to the end, explaining under what conditions an LTspice AC analysis can be compared with Hybrid-PI analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Why does the antenna only radiate 5MHz signal? Is it not supposed to radiate at the frequency of tank circuit? Also, is a 1nF coupling capacitor as in OP schematic large enough?

Comment: The 5MHz folded-dipole antenna described is actually a resonant load, and the 300-ohm equivalent resistor is a simplification, valid at the one frequency of 5 MHz. A 1000pf capacitor has reactance of 32 ohms at 5 MHz - would you consider it insignificant compared with the 300-ohm load? Perhaps - but I'd want to model that resonant antenna more accurately, including its transmission line connection to the amplifier..

Comment: I am using helical antenna of 24 awg copper wire of 5 turns and circumference = wavelength of tank circuit oscillations (2.4GHz) so that makes antenna load impedance approximately 140 ohms. A 32-ohm reactance is >1/5th, I wouldn't consider it insignificant, though I'm doubtful as to why the reactance is only calculated at 5MHz and not at 2.4GHz since the signal is already coupled by the time it reaches the capacitor.

Comment: OP mentioned a 5MHz source. Scaling a hybrid-PI to 2.4GHz is quite a stretch. If you find a linear 2-port model for BFU690, it would likely be S-parameters. You'd want a coupling capacitor to a 140 ohm antenna to have reactance much less than 140 ohms at 2.4 GHz.